# Make text move from right to left as a loop

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to reproduce [the comportment](https://pageloader-3cf2b.web.app/) of the `experience` text by using css. I tried to use my basic knowledge in `css` but it's not working as expected. I don't know how to manege the fact that it's "turning around" and not going back and forth.

```css
.animation {
    position: relative;
    animation: text 5s infinite;
}

@keyframes text {
    0% {
        right: 0px;
    }
    100% {
        left: 0px;
    }
    50% {
        left: 50%;
    }
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="animation">Hello<div/>
</div>
```

Comment: The properties should all be the same, you can;t mix and match right & left.

Comment: If you want it to be half visible on each side of the page, the normal "cheat" way of doing it is to have two elements animating 50% out of sync.

Comment: ok I get it, but how do I make the text going in one direction only from right to left in an infinite way and not doing a left to right, right to left effect ?

Comment: please check this link. i think it helps.
https://codepen.io/lewismcarey/pen/GJZVoG